# Package cl is deprecated, is there any easy fix for it?

Tags: cl

For the warning of

`Package cl is deprecated`

is there any easy fix for it?

Here is a piece of code I copied from somewhere (that I don't know how to fix):

```el
(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
(defun sanityinc/add-subdirs-to-load-path (parent-dir)
  "Adds every non-hidden subdir of PARENT-DIR to `load-path'."
  (let* ((default-directory parent-dir))
    (progn
      (setq load-path
            (append
             (remove-if-not
              (lambda (dir) (file-directory-p dir))
              (directory-files (expand-file-name parent-dir) t "^[^\\.]"))
             load-path)))))
```

Comment: There is *no error*, and *no error message*. The message is a warning - just an FYI/heads-up. `cl.el` is deprecated but not desupported. *Deprecated does not mean desupported.* You're encouraged to use its suggested replacement, but `cl.el` still works just fine.

Comment: No, it does not work _"just fine"_ for me, I wouldn't bother looking into it otherwise. That warning message is eclipsing the LSP mode import project prompt, causing all my projects to be in blacklisted directory. Took me quite a while to figure out why as the LSP mode was quite new and overwhelming to me.

Comment: I see. So the problem is other code that you're using, which itself stopped working with just `cl.el` loaded. There's nothing wrong, in itself, with using `cl.el`. But apparently your version of Purcell's code is out of date - see @manuel's answer. This is part of the fallout of people changing to use `cl-lib.el`: dependencies need to be updated/fixed.

Comment: For sure. thanks @Drew.

Comment: The easy way out is to use `cl-lib` instead of `cl`. A more robust route is to stop using the package all together -- it is a package with the clear purpose of porting Common Lisp packages to Emacs. There are several constructs in it which is plain wrong from an Emacs Lisp point of view, but apparently they are designed that way since "that is how Common Lisp" do it. The drawback of the cl-lib debacle is that useful functions like `union` no longer is available in normal elisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the code comes from Steve Purcell's [emacs.d](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-site-lisp.el).

He actually updated it to use `cl-lib` now, so you can try his more recent version:

```
(defun sanityinc/add-subdirs-to-load-path (parent-dir)
  "Add every non-hidden subdir of PARENT-DIR to `load-path'."
  (let ((default-directory parent-dir))
    (setq load-path
          (append
           (cl-remove-if-not
            #'file-directory-p
            (directory-files (expand-file-name parent-dir) t "^[^\\.]"))
           load-path))))
```

Comment: Don’t tell him that; he won’t learn as much.

Comment: You are right, but maybe it is still worth pointing him to the original code he copied just to look at the changes.

Comment: OMG, I was just shooting into the dark, and didn't expect anyone can answer it. And you've hit the nail precisely! THX!

Comment: _"Don’t tell him that; he won’t learn as much"_ I wish that db48x will need to maintain PL/I code once a year, then he _might_, just _might_, have some empathy.

Comment: In defense of @db48x, he provided an answer (and it is a good answer) to help you. Part of the problem is copying code *without understanding what it does*. And, yes, copying the updated code fixes the problem, but understanding the code that you are copying enough so that you can debug it when (not if) problems arise is important: "give a man a fish ..." and all that...

Comment: I’ve done a lot of software archaeology in my day, and I know well the temptation to blindly copy some code to get things working. That lack of understanding will always come back to bite us eventually. I could go on at length, but thinking about it gives me flashbacks of my work with autoconf/automake.

Comment: Sigh, putting someone into a fire every five years won't make him a good firefighter. You need to ask yourself, does he even have the basic knowledge and skills to fight the fire before putting him into the fire. Throwing a baby into a river will not force him to learn swimming fast either. It will only drown the baby. There are always things we don't know, and not everybody want to be a car mechanic when all he want is just to drive his car. Have some sympathy, please.

Comment: Anyone that uses Linux, have you ever heard Linux kernel people complaining that the average John is not understanding/helping/contributing in kernel development? Why some elisp people think he has the right to lecture the world? I guess most people comes here to get helps, not to get ashamed.

Comment: There was no attempt to shame AFAICS (after all, it was a comment on an answer, not on the question): maybe he should have added a smilie, but I took it as a tongue-in-cheek remark. And yes, you might just want an answer to the question and move on with your life, but these postings are used by people long after the initial question/answer session: it is useful to have answers explaining the *why*, not only the *how*. In fact, the *why* answers stand the test of time much better. My advice is: assume positive intent - I think you'll be much happier in the long run :-)

Comment: yeah, true. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the first line, which loads the `cl` package, and then fix any errors that result.

In particular, functions like `remove-if-not` are now called `cl-remove-if-not`, and are always available (technically they are autoloaded). The `cl` package just adds an alias for it called `remove-if-not` to allow older code to still work.

Comment: On the off-chance we have to use old versions of emacs, too, is there an idiom we should use?  Something like `(if (< emacs-major-version XXX) (remove-if-not ...) (cl-remove-if-not ...))`. That's pretty cumbersome actually: I guess we should live with the deprecation warning for a while yet. Looks like XXX = 28.

Answer (score 0):

I think my reason for getting this error was I was loading complete

```
(load "complete")
```

After removing this, the warning went away.